# How to slove “not assignable to parameter of type never” error in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to write a function in typescript. But it is showing an error like “not assignable to parameter of type never”

```
@Input('starCount') public starCount: number = 5;


  showStars() {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.starCount; index++) {
      this.ratingArr.push(index);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is showing the error? Is it runtime or compile time?  What line is showing the error?

Comment: @JeffryHouser I fixed the problem. I appreciate your concern. 

Actually the problem was : When I was pushing index into ratingArr then it was showing error like “not assignable to parameter of type never”.The problem was in declaring ratingArr.

"ratingArr = [ ]" my first declaration was like this. But It was fixed after declaring as "ratingArr : [ ] = [ ]" . Just after moved to any type from never!